# Is it possible to laser cool without using spatially-varying magnetic fields and above zero degrees?

Tags: laser, quantum-optics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms, optical-lattices

As the title says, is it possible to laser cool without generating a weak quadrupolar magnetic field? Also, if I wasn't trying to achieve extremely low temperatures is it possible to use laser cooling when gas temps are above 0 degrees? If not, why not?

Comment: Are you interested in a cooling theme without magnetic fields or without a  quadrupolar magnetic field? What is the temperature you like to achieve? Why is a setup without magnets important?

Comment: I'm interested in generating cooling without magnetic fields or magneto-optical traps. This is for a specific application not for a scientific experiment, I don't need ultra cold temps just a reduction or slowing of the gas speed.

Comment: There is a fine line between engineering and experimental physics. Furthermore, most questions which focus on applications are closed on this site. However, I feel that your question is currently too vague to be answered. Adding background information about the application is absolutely necessary, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to laser cool without generating a weak quadrupolar magnetic field?

Yes. [Optical molasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_molasses) cooling does not require any magnetic fields. But there is nothing providing a restoring force and hence "trapping"$^\dagger$. Experimentally, you usually first do a MOT and then an optical molasses stage.

> is it possible to use laser cooling when gas temps are above 0 degrees

"above 0 degrees" as opposed to what? Negative temperatures?

For laser cooling to have an effect you would need your gas do be isolated from the environment, e.g. in a vacuum, so that it does not rethermalise to the old temperature. Without some sort of spatial-trapping (e.g. MOT), I would assume you could in principle still do laser cooling but you'd need massive laser beams and a lot of optical power.

$^\dagger$: In a [magneto-optical trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_trap) (MOT), the magnetic fields are not strong enough to *trap* the atoms magnetically, rather they just modulate the light so the trapping is still provided by a (now modulated) optical force.

Comment: Apologies, I was under the impression the gas cloud had to be relatively cold before beginning laser cooling. Not sure where I picked that up.

Comment: So I as understand it optical molasses cannot trap atoms, they simply diffuse out of the cooling region over time, when atoms diffuse out do they return to their pre-cooled excited state?

Comment: If the system is "closed"; then the energy is conserved. So if you have reduced energy via cooling, that energy will not come back. Hence why it is good to have it in a vacuum, so as to keep the system closed. Molasses provides a force onto the atoms, so there will be some pressure, but there is no restoring force (sth $\propto -z$) that would actually trap it.

Comment: Thank you, this answered what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

> If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use a magnetic field, you can always *chirp* your laser frequency.

Most ultra-cold atoms experiments starts with a Zeeman slower for a good reason : it's cheap to make and it allows to slow **all of the atoms** of a given beam with a thermal velocity distribution down to something where usually **all of the atoms** have a velocity close to $\simeq 10\,\text{m.s}^{-1}$.

The resonance condition between an atom with an eigen-pulsation $\omega_0$ moving at a velocity $v$ against a laser with a wave-number $k$ and a pulsation $\omega$ is :
$$
\omega=\omega_0-k\,v(z(t))+\frac{\mu_B}{\hbar}B(z)
$$
In most situations, the spatial configuration of the magnetic field $B(z)$ is tailord so that such resonance condition is satisfied along the whole trajectory $z(t)$ of any atom. This means that, along this scheme, the cooling process is *continuous* : at any point $z$ any time $t$, atoms will be cooled down.

If you don't want to use a magnetic compensation $B(z)$, nothing is stopping you from changing/*chirping* the laser frequency $\omega(t)$ *itself* along the trajectory $z(t)$ of an atom, such that the resonance condition reads :
$$
\omega(t)=\omega_0-k\,v(z(t))
$$
If this condition is satisfied for any $t$, only a fraction of an atomic beam can be slowed down : only those with a given initial velocity $v_0=v(z(0))$.

Chirped laser cooling as been successfully implemented at various occasions [1](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.996) but is rarely used in usual ultracold set-up since it allows to slow atoms only *batch per batch* (and not continuously unlike in a Zeeman slower), thus leading generally to quite low atomic densities.

[1](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.996) : [Laser Manipulation of Atomic Beam Velocities : Demonstration of Stopped Atoms and Velocity Reversal](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.996) W. Ertmer, R. Blatt, J. L. Hall, and M. Zhu ;
Phys. Rev. Lett. 54, 996